# Modifying Angular Material Datepicker popup

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, calendar, angular-material

I would like to use the Angular Material Datepicker in my Angular application, but I a not quite satisfied with the default behavior The datepicker normally opens the calendar as a popup under the input. Instead I would like for the calendar to be permanently opened so that the user can continue to view the calendar as he selects different dates.

I understand that there is an `opened` property that reflects the status of the popup:

[Angular Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#manually-opening-and-closing-the-calendar)

Could I achieve the desired behavior by permanently setting the property to true to prevent the calendar from closing?  I have never rally modified the default behavior of a library before...how would I go about this?

Perhaps a different approach would be separating the input from the calendar?  I wonder what the best design approach would be?